# Эмулятор андроида не показывает изменений

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

Здравствуйте. Установил все необходимое, [как тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/android1.php). Создаю проект, но когда запускаю эмулятор, то все мои изменения в `Strings.xml`, в нем не отображаются, вместо этого на экране эмулятора только надпись Android. В `Graphical Layout` в `main.xml` все изменяется, но в запущенном эмуляторе все та же надпись. Что делать?

[image: снимок]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эмулятор андроида грузится долго. Уверен что эмулятор до конца загрузился? После загрузки эмулятора нужно своё приложение ещё в нём запустить, если запуск происходит впервые. При изменении проекта обязательна перекомпиляция и повторный запуск.

Comment: При запуске проекта (Run) появляется это http://prntscr.com/4yhrv
Разве он не до конца загрузился?

Comment: Нет. Это только загрузка. Если совсем уж долго будет грузить, то измените настройки эмулятора. Например, уменьшите оперативную память.

Comment: Да. Это значит что он загрузился не до конца. Жди дольше. На моём компе последняя версия минут 5 грузится.

Comment: забыл... также можно грудзить более раннюю версию. Версии которые выходили пораньше грузятся на порядок быстрее. И кстати, если он у вас долго грузится, то тормазить будет просто ужас)))

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Действительно нужно было ждать дольше.